# Sitecore Fast Query Get Descendants Query Syntax Inconsistent

Tags: sitecore

I came across an old project previously written for Sitecore 6.4 and now updated to Sitecore 7.2.

There is a fast query that does not return results:

```
1. fast:/sitecore/content/Home/About Us/News//*[@@templatename='Newsletter']
```

I tried to tweak the query and these two are working fine:

```
2. fast:/sitecore/content/Home/About Us/News/descendant::*[@@templatename='Newsletter']

3. fast:/sitecore/content/Home/About Us/News/Newsletters//*[@@templatename='Newsletter']
```

The Newsletter items are not direct children of Newsletters item either, there is another layer in between.

So Why the query 1 does not work while 2 & 3 return exactly what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check your web.config setting for FastQueryDescendantsDisabled.
- Rebuild your Descendents table via Control Panel, Databases, Clean Up Databases

Reference: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf

Comment: In the OP he said that the Newsletter items are not direct children of Newsletters either, which discounted the `FastQueryDescendantsDisabled` theory for me. Cleaning up the DB is definitely a good idea, but since the `descendant::` axes worked this theory was discounted for me, as well. Was I mistaken in my conclusions?

Comment: Well the document states, if this setting has been toggled, a rebuild is necessary. So my theory was, this was the current situation. It would account for inconsistent results across the seemingly similar queries.

Comment: I definitely agree. Never noticed that part of the documentation and never saw it in the decompiled code. +1

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the number of descendants of "News" is under whatever the maximum returned items size is set to in the web config (`<setting name="Query.MaxItems" value="100" />`).

While you aren't returning items while looking at the descendants, it is possible that the older version of Sitecore only looks at the max number of items (which would be a bug). The fact that query 3 works and query 1 doesn't is says to me that this is likely the issue. Query 2 is trying to do the same thing, but queries 1 and 3 also happen to be the same syntax. Since all three are meant to do the exact same thing (the only exception being that `/News/Newsletters` is looking from deeper root item), I would expect that this is a bug.

You can test this by setting the value of the `Query.MaxItems` setting to a ridiculously high number, like 5000 (note that you should change the value back after testing, as this can greatly degrade performance). If query 1 now returns items, then this is your issue. Otherwise, try setting the value higher. If it still doesn't return values after that, then this is not your issue.

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: I would love to know why this was downvoted so that I can improve the post and/or provide further suggestions.

Comment: Wasn't me. Based on the limited information in OP, I see nothing wrong with your suggestion and gave it a +1

Comment: Thanks, @MarkCassidy - I didn't think it was you ;) Plus, I read your posts daily.

Comment: `The fact that query 1 works and query 3 doesn't` - Is that a typo? Should be the other way round (qry 1 doesn't work, qry 3 does) i think. Theory sounds good otherwise.

Comment: Great catch, @jammykam! Updated!